# Filtrar las columnas de un dataframe a partir de una cadena o una lista de cadenas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Intento filtrar las columnas de una dataframe con una variable de texto o un array de texto. Intenté :

```
def recommend_perfumes(perfumes_scores: pd.DataFrame(), features: str):
    # filtramos y solo obtenemos la columnas en features
    perfumes_scores = perfumes_scores[features]
    ...
```

Pero me devuelve:

```
TypeError: Index(...) must be called with a collection of some kind, 'sweet' was passed
```

Con `features`: `sweet` aqui esta la dataframe `perfumes_scores`:

```
perfumes_scores:                            unnamed: 0  sweet  gentle  elegant  mature  sexy  ...  grass  plants  big brands  luxury  well-known products
usually see in ads
_id                                                                         ...

5fd5e617260828c7646000aa           0    0.0     0.0      0.0     0.0   0.0  ...    0.0     0.0         0.0     0.0                  0.0                 0.0

5fd5e638260828c7646000b0           1    0.0     0.0      0.0     0.0   0.0  ...    0.0     0.0         0.0     0.0                  0.0                 0.0

5fd5e643260828c7646000b2           2    0.0     0.0      0.1     0.0   0.0  ...    0.0     0.0         0.0     0.0                  0.0                 0.0
```

Comment: ejemplo de datos que recibe la funcion?

Comment: ¿cómo estas invocando `recommend_perfumes`? ¿qué tipo de dato es `features`?

Comment: Hola @PatricioMoracho acabo de escribir mis datos y poner un ejemplo